# WebView error on Marshmallow

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm testing my app, and when I'll open a `WebView` with a player of videos (X web page) it Crash ... I'm getting the following error:

(Tablet, 1 GB Ram with S.O Marshmallow 6.0.1 )

```
W/cr_media: Requires BLUETOOTH permission
D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:30] Constructor
W/cr_AwContents: onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:59] isActive: false
I/cr_Ime: ImeThread is not enabled.
I/Choreographer: Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 2137
D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:59] isActive: false
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Deferred long-running timer task(s) to improve scrolling smoothness. See crbug.com/574343.", source: "Here is the link of player"(0)
D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:59] isActive: true
D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:68] hideSoftInputFromWindow
A/chromium: [FATAL:memory.cc(19)] Out of memory. size=316362752
W/google-breakpad: ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
W/google-breakpad: Chrome build fingerprint:
W/google-breakpad: 1.0
W/google-breakpad: 1
W/google-breakpad: 609e4c8b-a10e-4de4-8770-d4fbd1c9b36d
W/google-breakpad: ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 2229 (CompositorTileW)
Application terminated.
```

Sometimes the page open without problems, but when Im going to press play in a video, it crash again.

Someone know what about this problem? Could be just out of memory? ... The webView works correctly in 4.4.2 (Samsung S4) - 5.1 (Moto G) and 7.0 (S7 Edge) S.O, Thanks.

Edit: Code of `ExploraVideos` activity

```
public class ExploraVideos extends Activity {
    String ShowOrHideWebViewInitialUse = "show";
    private WebView webview ;
    private ProgressBar spinner;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_videos);

    webview =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    spinner = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());

    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webview.setOverScrollMode(WebView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
    webview.loadUrl("here is the link of player");
}

/*This allows for a splash screen (and hide elements once the page loads)*/
private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView webview, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // only make it invisible the FIRST time the app is run
        if (ShowOrHideWebViewInitialUse.equals("show")) {
            webview.setVisibility(webview.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

        ShowOrHideWebViewInitialUse = "hide";
        spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        view.setVisibility(webview.VISIBLE);
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    onDestroy();
}

}
```

Comment: Post your implementation please. Your code do some heavy process in main UI thread

Comment: @PaulChu Ok, im going to edit the post with code, thanks.

Comment: You did add splash screen on `Webview`, so 1 GB Ram maybe the problem:) Since it just crashes when you playing a video. Maybe this help you https://github.com/cprcrack/VideoEnabledWebView

Comment: Sure, that is the principal suspicious, but what about S4 ... Omg, it has 2GB ram ... Ok, let me see, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

try to use [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) to avoid Out of memory :
or try this :

`webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(url,data,"text/html","UTF-8",url);`

This seems to have fixed the high cpu use and memory leak .

Comment: I solved that with: webview.clearCache(true); Thanks, maybe I could try with your code (: